# Airflow cleared backfill tasks do not get picked by the scheduler

Tags: airflow

When a task in a successful backfill run is cleared DagRun with running state is created but it is not picked by the scheduler. Is this the expected behaviour?

If there are many of such DagRuns and the backfill command is executed, all the DagRuns will be ran at the same time, not following the max_active_runs parameter.

The only workaround I've found until now is to clear the tasks, then mark the dagruns (not the task instances) as successful via UI, and then run the backfill.

Answer (score 3):

Scheduler will not pick up manually created DagRuns (including `airflow backfill`), only scheduled ones. You should do `airflow clear` and run `airflow backfill` for the period again.

As for backfill not respecting `max_active_runs`, I believe this was fixed with https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/2454. What Airflow version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.10.1. It does respect max_active_runs when dagruns are created by the backfill process. But after clearing the tasks all the dagruns are created by the webserver. So when the backfill is called, it executes all of it straight away.

Comment: Yes, though after giving max_active_runs, all the dag runs were triggering simultaneously. I'm using 1.10.15. Is this fixed in the new version?

Comment: @Tula Fixed in 2.1.3 https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9975#issuecomment-901459686